# No aparece la app en Google Play Store para mi pais

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Hola hace unos días hice una app que subí al market de Google Play Store en España, pero no esta apareciendo en las búsquedas desde la propia app del Play Store cuando hago una búsqueda.
La busqueda la estoy haciendo desde tablets con Android 5 y Android 7

La app esta publicada y en producción, como podéis ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También esta disponible en España, como podéis ver

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si desde la tablet , desde un navegador web,introduzco la URL de la app me aparecen dos mensajes:

> Este elemento no esta disponible en tu país

y

> Es posible que esta aplicación no este optimizada para tu dispositivo

Pero no tiene sentido porque  la aplicacion es para Android 4.1 a 7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porqué no me aparece en las búsquedas desde la app de google Play? 
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A veces este tipo de problemas es debido a que tienes configurado un método de pago ligado a otro país, en el cual la App no estaría disponible. La tienda interpreta que tu país es el de tu método de pago. No sé si sea ese tu caso.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, mi app no aparece en el buscador pero en cuando accedo desde la play console si me redirecciona a la Google play, no encuentro ninguna información que me diga que puedo hacer, tal vez alguien me podría ayudar, se los agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son dos mensajes y causas diferentes:

> Este elemento no esta disponible en tu país

Aunque comentas que tu país es España, y esta disponible en tu país:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema en este caso debe ser que no has configurado tu método de pago, en este caso entra a:

https://wallet.google.com/manage/paymentMethods

aquí puedes configurar tus métodos de pago de acuerdo a tu pais

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Es posible que esta aplicación no este optimizada para tu dispositivo.

Este mensaje indica que podría no estar optimizada ya que no  has agregado las imágenes adecuadas para `TABLET`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]