# ¿Por qué una app no aparece en el Play Store de un dispositivo en específico?

Tags: android, google-play

Tengo una App publicada en Google Play Store. El otro día en el dispositivo de una persona la estuvimos buscando y la App no aparecía.

Lo primero que pensé es que podría ser debido a que la API de su dispositivo sea muy antigua (en mi App tengo el `minSdkVersion` establecido a la versión 19). Pero ignoro si las apps aparecen únicamente si tu dispositivo es compatible con ellas.

Mi pregunta es precisamente esa: **¿si una App tiene en el `minSdkVersion` la versión `X`, no aparece en los dispositivos con versiones más antiguas?**

**¿Si llevo la app a `minSdkVersion` 15 por ejemplo, eso afectaría en algo a la App?**

Planteo la pregunta aquí. Si consideran que tiene más cabida del otro lado, agradezco sus puntos de vista. Necesito saber qué hacer en este caso, si alguno de ustedes ha tenido experiencias parecidas.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element) se especifica que Google Play utiliza`uses-sdk` como filtro así que aparentemente si, si un dispositivo tiene una version del sdk mas baja que `minSdkVersion` no debería aparecer

Comment: Eso fue lo que pensé @Pikoh, pero no tenía la referencia que indicas en el enlace. Agradecería una respuesta si es posible para ti, dando así el tema por resuelto. Creo que llevaré la App a la API 15 como mínimo.

Comment: @A.Cedano bajar el nivel de API puede tener repercusiones, posiblemente tendrías que validar ciertos método o clases que son obsoletos, incluso si actualizaste tu aplicación seguramente aumentaste el targetSDK lo cual puede  indicar realizar adecuaciones. Puedes también conservar (retain) una versión que cubra las versiones anteriores a 19 , esta decisión depende que la complejidad de tu aplicación y el nivel de mantenimiento que requeriría continuar usando minSdkVersion 15, agregué información relacionada a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Filtrado de Google Play
>
> Google Play usa los atributos  declarados en el manifiesto de tu app para aplicarle filtrado y excluir dispositivos no cumplan con los requisitos de la versión de su plataforma. Antes de definir estos atributos, asegúrate de comprender los filtros de Google Play.

(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element)

Según se desprende de ese texto, Google Play efectivamente utiliza los elementos de `uses-sdk` para filtrar los dispositivos que tienen acceso a una aplicación.

En principio, bajar la versión de `minSdkVersion` no debería tener ninguna repercusión en tu aplicación, aunque sería importante realizar un test contra un dispositivo con ese sdk (creando, por ejemplo, un nuevo avd en android studio).

Por otro lado, API 15 está actualmente en un 0.3% de los dispositivos, no se si es suficientemente relevante como para bajar la versión mínima de sdk, pero eso ya es una consideración personal.

Answer (score 5):

Para que no se muestre una aplicación publicada en Google Play Store en el dispositivo de un usuario existen varias razones.

### **- El `minSdkVersion` establecido determina que dispositivos con cierto sistema operativo pueden instalar la aplicación.**

Constantemente vamos a realizar actualizaciones a nuestras aplicaciones y seguramente subiremos la versión de la API, en tu caso si cambiaste a 19, únicamente dispositivos con versión mínima de sistema operativo [Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4?hl=es-419) podrán instalar tu aplicación.

Es importante para esto conservar (retain) una versión de tu aplicación que pueda ser instalada en dispositivos con una API menor a la definida como minima de tu última versión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ver más información en :

[Filtrado de Google Play](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element)

Con respecto a tus preguntas:

> ¿si una App tiene en el minSdkVersion la versión X, no aparece en los
>   dispositivos con versiones más antiguas?

**`minSdkVersion` va a definir la mínima versión de sistema operativo en la cual se podría instalar tu aplicación y estaría disponible en Google Play Store para instalación.**

> ¿Si llevo la app a minSdkVersion 15 por ejemplo, eso afectaría en algo
>   a la App?

**Dependiendo de las clases que uses, posiblemente tendrías que realizar adecuaciones y validaciones dependiendo de API´s**, ejemplo:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = true;
if(pm != null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    } else {
        isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    }
}
```

---

#### Otras causas que pueden filtrar tu dispositivo :

### **- La aplicación, debe estar disponible en el país del usuario y además debes agregar un método de pago.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisar:
[No aparece la app en Google Play Store para mi pais](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148480/no-aparece-la-app-en-google-play-store-para-mi-pais)

### **- El uso de caracteristicas de hardware que no existan en ciertos dispositivos pueden evitar que tu aplicación se encuentre disponible para algunos usuarios**.

Si tu aplicación hace uso de cámara, bluetooth, microfono, NFC, WiFi , etc, y el dispositivo del usuario no cuenta con este hardware, la aplicación no estará disponible en Google Play.

Si no es requisito indispensable para el funcionamiento de tu aplicación alguna característica de hardware usada en tu aplicación puedes usar el atributo [**android:required**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element?hl=es-419#required), ejemplo:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
```

Lo anterior indica que los usuarios pueden no tener cámara en su dispositivo para usar la aplicación, por lo tanto esta estaría disponible en `Google Play` para usuarios sin esta característica de hardware.

> `android:required="true"` , significa que la aplicación no puede
>   funcionar, o no está diseñada para funcionar, cuando el dispositivo no
>   cuenta con la función especificada.
>
> `android:required="false"` para una función, significa que la
>   aplicación prioriza la función si está presente en el dispositivo,
>   pero que está diseñada para funcionar sin la función especificada en
>   caso de que sea necesario.

### **- Definición de [`<supports-screens`](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support?hl=es-419)**

Es muy común que deseemos configurar nuestra aplicación para especificar cierto tamaño de pantalla que permite la aplicación, sin embargo hay que tener cuidado con esta configuración ya que podríamos estar no permitiendo la disponibilidad de la aplicación para dispositivos con cierta medida de pantalla.

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true">
    </supports-screens>
```

La forma adecuada para que la aplicación funcione bien en pantallas grandes es seguir [la guía de Soporte de pantallas múltiples y proporcionar diseños alternativos para diferentes tamaños de pantalla](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support?hl=es-419).

### **- Propagación de aplicación en servidores**.

Hay que recordar que al subir nuestra aplicación a `Google Play` el tiempo que tardará en estar disponible varia dependiendo de la cantidad de usuarios y no es automático así que hay que esperar desde unos minutos a algunas horas.