# Play store no indexa a la busqueda mi app

Tags: android, google-play

En el proyecto de mi app, complete la ficha de Play Store en Play Console junto a todos los requisitos exigidos, pude subirlo y tengo la URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iglesia.nvk de mi programa en Play Store andando.

**El problema es que a la hora de buscar el programa desde el Play Store no esta, si no se ingresa por url, no lo puedo ubicar.**

Espere 10 dias con esperanza que lo indexen. En que estoy fallando?, que puedo intentar?, busque acerca de esto pero hay muy poca data, lo poco que vi intente pero sin exito. Gracias.

Aqui va el gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29 
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3" 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iglesia.nvk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/pierfrancescosoffritti/maven"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

Adicionalmente a esto, agrego una imagen de como yo lo veo en google play desde la url.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El lg 870 es mi cel y no lo puedo ver. Que podra ser?, muchas gracias jorge y los que han leido mi desesperacion al ser mi primer programa.

//--------------------------------------------------------

Y el Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.iglesia.nvk" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarSplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".YoutubeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarSplash" />
        <activity
            android:name=".YoutubeActivity_playback"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarSplash" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Y como dato adicional esta advertencia me aparece al revisar la app para publicar una nueva version:

APK no optimizado

Advertencia:

Este APK genera código y recursos que no se utilizan y se envían a los usuarios de todos modos. Puedes reducir el tamaño de tu app mediante el formato Android App Bundle. Si no optimizas la app para las configuraciones de los dispositivos de los usuarios, esta tendrá un tamaño de descarga e instalación más grande que lo que realmente necesita. Las apps de mayor tamaño tienen tasas de éxito de instalaciones más bajas y ocupan más espacio de almacenamiento en los dispositivos de los usuarios.

Resolución:

Usa el formato Android App Bundle para optimizar las configuraciones de los dispositivos de forma automática o adminístralas por tu cuenta con varios APK.

Comment: Te sugiero agregar tu build.gradle, tal vez ahí se puede encontrar la razón, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Veo que tienes minSdkVersion 19, es un poco raro, podrías agregar que configuracion tienes en tu AndroidManifest.xml por favor ?

Comment: En seguida......

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la cual no aparece tu aplicación al ser buscada en Google Play es porque no es soportada para la mayoría de los dispositivos, de hecho en mi caso un ejemplo, tengo dispositivos con sistema operativo 4.4, 6.1, 7.0, y 8.0 pero tu aplicación no es soportada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por esta razón al realizar una búsqueda no se encontrará si los dispositivos asociados a tu cuenta no soportan la aplicación.

Para conocer varias razones por las cuales puede ser filtrada revisa mi respuesta:

[¿Por qué una app no aparece en el Play Store de un dispositivo en específico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215354/95)

---

En el `build.gradle` que muestras en tu actualización se tiene un `versionName` con valor "1.7".

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29 
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3" 
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName "1.7"
        ...
    }
}
```

Pero en los detalles de la aplicación en la tienda indica que es otra versión:

> Updated March 24, 2020 Size
>   3.4M Installs 1+
>   **Current Version
>   1.5** Requires Android
>   4.2 and up

La versión no corresponde, revisa si no subiste otro .apk que probablemente solo funcione con Android 9.0

Comment: ahora edito mi pregunta para colocar mas detalles, gracias jorge, estoy desesperado no se a quien acudir ni tampoco resolverlo.

Comment: No te preocupes tiene solución, @multiuso_55 saludos.

Comment: Hola , viste mi actualización?, si es la 1.7  debería de ser esa versión en la tienda pero dice 1.5 @multiuso_55

Comment: Hola jorge, espero q andes bien, gracias a Dios anoche se indexo despues de casi 2 sem, y le tire 2 actualizaciones y creo que lo atore jaja, dice procesando en el play console. Muchas gracias por todo jorge que Dios te bendiga.